# How to turn off flashing items in taskbar?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

Windows 10, sometimes background applications need to get your attention, so they flash the taskbar until you acknowledge them.  That is super annoying in general as I may be busy and not able to respond immediately to something that's not actually critical (flashing chat windows most notably).  If I'm remote desktop over a slow link it's far worse as the blinking eats up precious bandwidth and slows me down.

Is there a way to block apps from flashing there?  If they went to simple inverse video instead it would be just as obvious without the above issues.  I found several references on-line so far that all basically restate the registry key hack from http://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-flashing-taskbar-buttons-windows which does not work (seems to have zero effect).

Open to registry hacks that actually work or even third party software if available!

Comment: Haven't found a solution that works, Microsoft seems to be ignoring this.
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/apps_windows_10-winapps-appscat_social/how-do-i-stop-icons-from-appearing-and-flashing-in/fd405a8b-750a-4c8f-a37c-165db509988b#:~:text=Right%2Dclick%20on%20an%20empty,buttons'%20setting%20and%20disable%20it.
https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/35130118-flashing-icon-in-task-bar-for-unread-messages
https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/18871387-allow-us-to-turn-of-flashing-taskbar-notifications

Answer (score 2):

The following solution isn't making any permanent changes, only
in-memory redirecting/patching some function calls in explorer.exe. If you execute it manually to test out, then log out and back in, and then everything should be reset (or simply restart explorer.exe in Task Manager). I use it myself on Windows 10. However I do have to mention in case if you want to test it first, that it only works if it's executed before any taskbar flashing occurs. So keep that in mind.

Install AutoHotkey v1.1 and download DisableFlashingTaskbarButtons.ahk from the following GitHub repository: https://github.com/Ciantic/DisableFlashingTaskbarButtons

Then make a shortcut of the AHK script and go to its properties window, and to the right of the target value add  `-NoMsgBox`. Then copy the shortcut, press WinKey+R, write `shell:startup` in the Run dialog box and press Enter. Finally paste the shortcut in the Startup folder which just opened and then you're done!

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I found while Microsoft doesn't fix this bug is to use this little app to send apps to the tray bar: https://github.com/fcFn/traymond/releases